# What permissions might be missing on error 229 from 'tables' node on SSMS object explorer

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, permissions, user-management

I have just added a login to test an ETL process on a database and I get the error described below when connect using the account I click on the 'Tables' tab on the object explorer on SSMS on a database with the login set up as a user.

> Failed to retrieve data for this
>   request (Microsoft.SqlServer.SmoEnum)
>
> Additional Information
>
> An exception occured while executing a
>   Transact-SQL statement or batch
>   (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)
>
> The SELECT permissions was denied on
>   the object 'extended_properties'
>   database 'mssqlsystemresource', schema
>   'sys'.  (Microsoft SQL Server, Error:
>   229).

This looks like it should be a noddy mistake but I can't find anything that fixes the problem in a quick google search.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you get this error when you log in as SA (or equivalant administrator rights)?

Comment: No. Only when I log in as the user I just created.

Comment: I posted a somewhat similar question on stackoverflow here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2002773/permissions-issue-in-ssms-the-select-permission-was-denied-on-the-object-exten

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might not be the same thing but I was getting that error today.

Turned out that in my haste to grant a user full access to a database I ticked all the boxes under role members including db_denydatareader, db_denydatawriter.